# How do you use the Ubuntu command line to pull a project that's been uploaded onto Git?

Tags: git, ubuntu, command-line

I (think) I've set up Git correctly. How do I pull my friend's project that he's shared with me so that I can help him with it?

Comment: Do you have the URL for your friend's project?

Comment: [clone](http://progit.org/book/ch2-1.html#cloning_an_existing_repository) it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By "uploaded onto Git" I assume you mean "uploaded onto GitHub". That's an important distinction: Git is a source control system. GitHub is a place to host repositories that are controlled via git.

To clone a repository that is hosted on GitHub, first log into your github account and go to the main page (https://github.com/). Off to the right, just under the tiles at the top will be a section labeled "Your Repositories". The one your friend shared with you should be listed. Click on it. Then near the top of this new page, you'll see a git clone url like "git@github.com:abc/xyz.git". Copy this and then run the command:

```
git clone git@github.com:abc/xyz.git
```

Comment: You can use the HTTPS url as well if the connection didn't established by ssh url. Also make sure that Git is already installed on your machine. For instance if it is Ubuntu install git first: sudo apt-get install git

Comment: what if it is a private project ? İt will ask for username and password ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to clone a repository from GitHub, you will need to follow these steps:

1. Get the HTTPS URL of the repo as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOgom.png)
2. On a terminal window type the command (be sure to enter the URL you copied in step 1):

   `git clone HTTPS_URL_COPIED_IN_STEP_1.git`
3. If you are asked for your GitHub username & password enter them now. Please note that the username is **not** your email address.

If you have 2-factor authentication turned on, you'll need to create a personal access token first.*Your regular password will not work if you use 2-factor authentication on GitHub.*

Follow the instructions [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) to create the token. Once this is done, enter this in place of the password after step 2.

Comment: Starting August 2021 github removed support for [passwords](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/), so you'll need a token or something anyway.

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
git pull origin <branch>
```